# mx:button fillColors not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I work with FB4.6 and I try to apply a fillColor on my button.

```
package fr.int.component.customNavTab
{
    import mx.controls.Button;
    import mx.controls.ToggleButtonBar;
    import mx.core.IFlexDisplayObject;
    import mx.states.OverrideBase;

    public class IconToggleButtonBar extends ToggleButtonBar

    {

        public function IconToggleButtonBar()
        {
            super();

        }

        [Inspectable (enumeration='left,right,top,bottom', defaultValue='left')]  
        public var labelPlacement:String = 'left';  
        public var color:uint;


        override protected function createNavItem(label:String, icon:Class=null):IFlexDisplayObject
        {
            var b:Button = Button (super.createNavItem(label,icon));
            b.labelPlacement = labelPlacement;

            b.setStyle('fillColors', [0x86C543, 0xE6E6E6]);
            return b;
        }



    }
}
```

But this has no effect on my button.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the quotes around the second parameter of setStyle.

Comment: should work... how about setting fillAlphas to [1,1] as well ?

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in a string **'[0x86C543, 0xE6E6E6]'** where you need an array. The [] brackets denote an Array but by placing this in quotes it is read in as a string.

Change this to

```
b.setStyle('fillColors', [0x86C543, 0xE6E6E6]);
```

Comment: I remove quote but no effect.

Comment: Are you using a mx or spark button?

Comment: Are you sure? If so please post some more code so we can take a deeper look.

Answer (score 0):

`fillColors` on `mx:Button` works only in Halo theme. So you need to use Flex 3 SDK or try something like this in Flex 4 http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/07/14/using-the-halo-theme-in-flex-4/

**EDIT**:
Here's an example. Try to create project with Flex 4 SDK and put this code to application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
        mx|Button{
            fillColors: #FF0000, #00FF00
        }
    </fx:Style>
    <mx:Button />
</s:Application>
```

There will be a warning `The style 'fillColors' is only supported by type 'mx.controls.Button' with the theme(s) 'halo'.` And it doesn't matter that you are using `mx:Button`, the fact that you need to use halo theme matters. So if you want change fillColors of `mx:Button` you have 2 choices that I've posted before

Comment: as you see he is already using mx:Button by declaring import mx.controls.Button;